# Redirect Large Number of URLs (HTML Files) to Wordpress

Tags: php, html, apache

I have over 2000 HTML files that are now in Wordpress blog. I have the URL Map of Old_file.html and new wordpress URL.

I want 301 redirect but don't want to add 2000 lines to htaccess. Can you please suggest how to accomplish this using PHP so that when there is a request for old url, the php script should lookup into the database and redirect(301) to the new URL ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your map a [mod_rewrite rewrite map](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) like this:

```
# old    new
Old_file new-url
```

Then you just need to register the rewrite map in the server or virtual host configuration:

```
RewriteMap examplemap txt:/path/to/file/map.txt
```

And finally set a rule that does the redirect (either in your server/virtual host configuration or an .htaccess file):

```
RewriteCond %{examplemap:$1} .+
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.html$ /blog/%0 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: So far getting internal server error...

Registering Rewrite Map  - Does this happen by including in .htaccess file or something else ?

And why is the /blog/ for ?

Comment: I think I know what Registering is now. Will look into it.

Comment: @Chetan: `RewriteMap` can only be used in the server or virtual host configuration file.