# Optimizing large number of wordpress URL redirects in NGINX

Tags: wordpress, redirect, nginx

On one of the WordPress sites I am managing the clients wants change a large number *(current count is 200+)* of URLs to clean scheme.

I am trying find the most optimal scheme for handling this change.

Changes are quite specific in some URLs so having a hard time coming up a regex scheme

**What the change looks like**

```
From:
/product/*Product Name*-*Custom String X*/

To:
/buy/*Category*/*Product Name*-*Custom String Y*/
```

*(Custom Strings are rather different and very specific to every product / Uses WordPress Taxonomy in backend)*

Options I have come up with :

**1) Use NGINX HttpMapModule**
Insipred from : [Redirect Large Number of URLs (HTML Files) to Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727335/redirect-large-number-of-urls-html-files-to-wordpress) Answer

**2) Write a Custom Router.php**

Mix NGINX redirect with php router

```
location /product{
...
return 301 https://...domain.../router.php?$request_uri;
...
}
```

And let router.php search file for new url and do a redirect.
*BUT* this may cause "too many redirection* in some edge case as
*NGINX>router.php>wordpress internal routing*

Is there any other option which I am missing ? And If not then which way perform the best ?

Comment: Won't that be easier to change it at wp_posts database? Using SELECT then a batch UPDATE statements or some sort.

Comment: @hcheung The 301 redirects are needed for SEO. Are you suggesting I db changes to reflect both URLs? Is that optimized ?

Comment: If I were you, I would changes all the past urls once for all, update the sitemap and setup the correct server directives.  The way your are doing may cause a lot of redirects which affect SEO score as well.

Comment: @hcheung unfortunately I cannot let old urls 404 as they were indexed already